# python error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'setdefault'

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to run the inverse_dictionary project using this command.

[image]

But every time I'm trying to run I faced the error.

I can't figure out what the problem is. Please help me fix it.

Comment: Can't you just use `{v: k for k, v in dict(one=1, two=2, three=3).items()}`?

Comment: That is a clear answer. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem line is `inverse = inverse.setdefault(val, key)`. `setdefault` returns the value, in this case its a `str`. This line sets the inverse to a `str`, not a `dict`. The second time it is run, inverse is a `str`, which does not have a setdefault method.